# jmUIImage- Is it predefined or userdefined?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

While working with xcode, I saw a new line **jmUIImage** and i try to execute the code in my SDK. But i got a strange Error. The error is

> jmUIImage is undeclared

I thought it is a predefined function of Xcode. Is it a predefined or userdefined function?

```
jmUIImage *buttonImageNormal = [UIImage imageNamed:@"White Button.png"];
    UIImage *stretchableButtonImageNormal = [buttonImageNormal  stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:12 topCapHeight:0]
```

What it indicates and why i got the error ?

Comment: you positioned your cursor before UIImage and then your cat pressed the j and m key. Remove jm and done.

Comment: @MatthiasBauch Yes Ur right i Executed it without jm it works well . But what it will be, Error while coding  or it refers any function. Thats my doubt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the bug came from the book "Beginning iPhone Development". On [page 85](http://books.google.de/books?id=s-NqSq5jqpsC&pg=PA85&lpg=PA85&dq=jmUIImage&source=bl&ots=7j1rDbD0uv&sig=XlATJnQxa3RXEXesHWKh9mwxaAw&hl=de&sa=X&ei=BFF5T6GlNYv2sgaBp9S2BA&ved=0CFwQ6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q=jmUIImage&f=false) you can see `jmUIImage`.

This is just a typo. As you can see in the code the object that is assigned to the `jmUIImage` instance is just an `UIImage`. That does not make much sense because you could never use any methods defined in the `jmUIImage` class on this object.

```
jmUIImage *buttonImageNormal = [UIImage imageNamed:@"White Button.png"];
```

If I would encounter such code I would just try it with `UIImage`.
Another hint for a typo is that the name `jmUIImage` does not start with a capital letter. And classes (and only classes) should always start with a capital letter in Objective-C.
And when you subclass you should not include the Prefix-Letters in your classname. A proper naming for a subclass of `UIImage` would be `JMImage`.

If it smells like a typo and looks like a typo it probably is just a typo.